Auto Reload for Node server and Web Browser Refresh using Nodemon
I'm trying to use Nodemon to auto reload my server and as a result, refresh my browser whenever I make a change to a JSON or JS file.
My Web Server is located in directory 1 and my content with some JS, JSON, Angular and HTML files are in directory 2 for easier separation.
I installed Nodemon as I saw somewhere that it auto reloads the server whenever there's a change in the directory of my app.js file which is in location 1 (web server).
When I make a change to a JSON file in my content directory, the log in the terminal suggests that Nodemon is auto reloading the server but when I refresh my browser, the changes don't reflect and I have to manually restart the server to see them.
I created a nodemon.json file in my web server directory which didn't seem to solve my issue either:
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": [
    "/Users/shaned/repos/backend/server", //list of files, you want to watch for changes
    "/Users/shaned/repos/frontend/content"
  ],
  "ext": "js json html"
}

Also, I get this error after awhile:
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

This is how I run the server in the CLI:
NODE_PATH=$SERVER nodemon $SERVER/backend/app.js --conf $TEST_ROOT/default.conf --test:geoip:code ""

The web site currently works on Angular with Node v10.24.1 with NPM v6.14.12. I also work on MacOS so if there's an alternative package or solution, I'm open to suggestions.

I hadn't realised that I was actually on node v8 when installing nodemon which gave me some errors.
Switching to v10 and reinstalling nodemon with the following updated cmd solved my issues:
NODE_PATH=$SERVER nodemon $SERVER/Backend/app.js -w /Frontend/content -e "js,json,html" --signal SIGTERM /Backend --conf $TEST_ROOT/default.conf --test:geoip:code ""

